# Unable to fix my errors when trying returning oldest file in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I had a look online and referred to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/552600/how-can-i-find-the-oldest-file-in-a-directory-tree) but, as I'm writing my own script, I'm not sure how to correct my errors...I've tried fixing them myself but there are just more errors that pop up that I need to fix...

- line 3: unsure if necessary?
- line 5: unsure if this is even the correct code - I don't think it's checking what I would like it to check
- line 6: unsure how to get the correct output in the `-name` bit (to show the name of actual oldest file)

My code-

```sh
1 #!/bin/bash
2 echo "Search for oldest files"
3 find ~ -name "*. "
4 echo "Performing task"
5 find -type $HOME f -print $HOME f "%T+ %p\0" | sort | head -n 1;
6 echo "The oldest file in the list is " -name;
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you only trying find the oldest file?
2. `file` needs a path as the first argument or it can be ommitted. `find -type $HOME f` is probably supposed to be `find $HOME -type f`.
3. There is also a 2. `$HOME` too much.
4. You split the `printf` into `print f`
5. You don't save the output from `find` in a variable, therefore you can't access the name in line
6. Also you access variables with a $ not with a - or what is `-name` supposed to be at the end?
7. You changed `\n` to `\0` so everything is a single line and `head -n 1` doesn't do anything
8. I added cut to extract the filename without the timestamp.

This should do what you want:

```sh
echo "Search for oldest files"
echo "Performing task"
oldest_file=$(find $HOME -type f -printf "%T+ %p\n" | sort | head -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f2-)
echo "The oldest file in the list is $oldest_file"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggested edits ! It's a practice exercise where I created some dummy files on my computer and challenge myself to see if I can retrieve the oldest created dummy file.

I made a few edits before I saw your response and also incorporated from of your suggestions but I'm still getting the "no such file or directory" message.

For example, I've created files back-to-back (files called tech, hub, phone), then the code should give me "The oldest file in the list is tech".